# Possible Android Dependency Issues

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I'm creating an Android library that other developers will use in their applications. This is done through a .aar file which I will be providing. My library is dependent on google's play services library. I have the following questions concerning this:

- What happens if the developer who is using my api also includes google's play services library as a dependency?
- What will happen in the case he includes a different version of the library?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if the developer who is using my api also includes google's play services library as a dependency?

This is not a problem.

> What will happen in the case he includes a different version of the library?

This will not work, it's not possible to use different versions of play services at a time.

Comment: So in the case of my second question, lets say a newer version of Google play services is released, will the developer who is using my library be able to use it? Based on your answer I think this will not work. Are there any methods so that a developer who is using my library can use a newer version of play services even though my library is using an older version?

Comment: Right, this will not work. He must stick with the version is used in the lib until you have updated it.
Maybe there is a way to handle this via proguard and not using explicit version numbers in your aar , but i'm not aware of this. Sorry.